# Dat.GUI: A few questions

Tags: class, three.js, dat.gui

I'm making a small billiards game in THREE.js, and have opted to use Dat.Gui as a GUI library. I have a few small questions regarding the latter:

- First Question: Can I make a class that returns the GUI?

Currently I have a mygui.js file where I put the code of the gui (the example code[[1](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/example.html)], let's say), and I include that in mygame.html before the main.js. However, all other objects (table, balls, lights, etc) are classes and I'd like to do that too with the GUI. When I place everything inside a

```
class MyGUI {
    constructor() {
        //javascript part of the example here
        return gui;
    }
}
```

and then call in main.js

```
var mygui = new MyGUI();
```

the GUI isn't showing up, but when I don't include the class and the line in main.js, it works. I have downloaded *dat.gui.min.js* and included it in the html.

- Second Question: I want to change variables now and then based on when I call the gui's change function, but how would I go about that without classes (should that not work)?
- Third Question: I want to use the GUI, only to display values. Users are not supposed to change it. Can I make the GUI read-only? (to be clear: changing the values in the GUI will not change gameplay, they're just textual representations of the state of the game)
- Fourth Question: I want to remove the top part of the GUI (where you can load/save presets or something). How do I do that?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage)?

Comment: I had, but at first glance it didn't answer my questions. After a second look, I realise that the cleaner answer to question #2 than `gui.__controllers[i].setValue( newVal )` is at your link, page 9. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Progressive insights:

1. 
2. As linked by @prisoner849: [Page 9](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#9--Updating-the-Display-Automatically) of the example/tutorial. 

   `gui.add(param, 'theSetting').listen();
   function updateTheSetting(newVal){ param.theSetting = newVal; }`

When `param.theSetting` is updated, **and** the added param `listen()`s to it, a change in the param.theSetting will automatically update the GUI.

3. 
4. Don't use `gui.remember( someParameters )` and the save part will dissapear.